# Why does this exclude pattern for rsync give different results when the source directory has a trailing slash?

Tags: rsync

When I do something like

```
rsync -a --exclude=/e/garbage /e /dest
```

the exclusion works, but with

```
rsync -a --exclude=/e/garbage /e/ /dest/e
```

it doesn't. I'm using version 3.0.7 protocol version 30 under cygwin, in case it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in the second case, you're rsyncing the contents of `/e/`, and the filter pattern is rooted there, not up one level. So, you need to remove that from your exclude:

```
rsync -a --exclude=/garbage /e/ /dest/e
```